# When implement batch norm in Tensorflow, how to reuse beta and gamma but do not reuse moving mean and moving variance at the same time?

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

currently I want to build two convolutional neural networks using tensorflow. Besides, I also use batch norm in my networks(tf.contriib.layers.batch_norm for example). I want these two networks to share all weights except moving_mean and moving_variance in batch-norm.

My question is that, if I just define a reuse variable scope in this way:

```
def BatchNorm(x, is_reuse, *args):
    with tf.variable_scope('Network', reuse=is_reuse):
        return tf.contriib.layers.batch_norm(x, *args)
# set is_reuse = False when building the first NN
# set is_reuse = True when building the second one
```

However, in this way, all variables in batch-norm, including beta, gamma, moving_mean, moving_variance will totally be set reuse=True or reuse=False. But I only want reuse bata and gamma and do not reuse moving_mean and moving_variance.

Implementing batch-norm by myself is one solution, but I wonder whether there is any tensorflow function can do these things for me, so that what I only need to do is to set some parameter is True or pass into some tensor.

Thanks a lot!